# How to disable Undo in Rich Text Box in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to disable undo redo feature of textbox and richtextbox.
Please tell how to do this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I can think of a couple really good reasons.  1) memory usage, 2) performance, 3) annoy the users.

Comment: Here's one I'm currently dealing with: disabling redo and undo in MaskedTextBox. It's just too much of a pain to implement (at least in WPF since you basically have to re-implement redo and undo and put the caret back in the right place every time); not worth it at all since they will probably never even get used. I know of 2 reputable sources that disable these functions in their masked textboxes: 1) [jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/), 2) [Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/prducts/wpf/masked-text-box), also 3) this textbox that I'm typing in (not masked though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the **UndoLimit** property of your Textbox to **0**. Should work.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [IsUndoEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isundoenabled.aspx) property:

```
<TextBox Name="yourTextBox" IsUndoEnabled="False" />
```